# youtube-dl output to multiple paths

Tags: bash, youtube, youtube-dl

I have the following bash script to download youtube videos as an mp3 file using youtube-dl:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p 'URL: ' url

youtube-dl -f 'bestaudio' --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 --audio-quality 0 -o "Z:/youtube-dl/%(title)s.%(ext)s" $url

read -p "Press [Enter] to exit..."
```

What I would like to do is make it save the mp3 file to multiple paths instead of only saving to the path on my Z: drive. How can I do this?

Adding multiple -o options doesn't work, since the last one overrides all previous ones.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `--get-filename` option to retrieve the video data for the filename, use that and copy the file to other locations afterwards:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

read -p 'URL: ' url

filename="$(youtube-dl --get-filename -o "%(title)s" "$url").mp3"
youtube-dl -o "Z:/youtube-dl/$filename" -f 'bestaudio' --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 --audio-quality 0 $url
echo /second/path /third/path | xargs -n 1 cp "Z:/youtube-dl/$filename"

read -p "Press [Enter] to exit..."
```

If you want to avoid reading from Z: just use a different or a temporary path like `/tmp` as the first one.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot for taking the time and looking into it.

For anyone that may find this in the future:
One issue I had was with the file extension, --get-filename was returning a file with the ending webm, but since youtube-dl is setup to convert the file to mp3 once downloaded, the cp command was throwing an error since the file formats don't match. I replaced %(ext)s with mp3, since the resulting file will always be an mp3, and it works like intended now.

Comment: @verize My bad, I corrected the answer.